# How to create Google Apps Script?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I use service account and it's my code:

**test.py**

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
KEY_DICT = {...}
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(KEY_DICT, SCOPE)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
script = discovery.build('script', 'v1', http=http)

file_name = 'test.gs'
file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.script'
}
media = MediaFileUpload(file_name, mimetype='text/plain')
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
script_id = file.get('id')

request = {
    "function": 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
}
response = script.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=script_id).execute()
print response['response'].get('result')
```

**test.gs**

```
function getFoldersUnderRoot() {
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folders = root.getFolders();
  var folderSet = {};
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderSet[folder.getId()] = folder.getName();
  }
  return folderSet;
}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 37, in <module>
    response = script.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=script_id).execute()
  File "site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/1LI...4y0:run?alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.">
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should deploy the script? Maybe this works only web UI. I didn't find how to do it via dev console.

Comment: If you're sticking with Python, follow the setup in the [Python Quickstart for Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/python) as there's a step-by-step guide. . If you want to use Apps Script easily, I think you should go for the Javascript implementations. The [Class Drive App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) using JS is rife with good samples.

Comment: The tutorial uses a client credentials, but I would like a server credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are known issues with using service accounts and the Google App Scripts API. You can read more about this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36763096).

The work-around is to user client credentials to generate a refresh token manually, and then use the refresh token as a means of getting an authorization token.